# Is there a way to call a function when any setter is used in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, setter

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
class Company(var address: String, var name: String, var owner: String){
  var modified=LocalDateTime.now()
}

int main(){
 var company=Company("Adrd", "test", "Jack")
println(${company.modified}} //gives time
 Thread.sleep(3000)
company.address="address2"
println(${company.modified})//should give time +3 sec


}
```

Everytime some changes to the value of `address`, `name`, `owner`,... are made I want to change `modified=LocalDateTime.now()`

Is it possible to call `modified=LocalDateTime.now()` for all 3 setters at the same time

Comment: I'm guessing the best way to do this might be to use [observable](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/observable.html) delegates for each property, with an `onChange` function that records the time. (Or you could write your own delegate based on `observable`.)

Comment: Yes, you could use that [as documented in the Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#optimized-cases-for-delegated-properties), but at the same time, if the class is simple and you want a simple solution, make the properties private, and create your own Setter that increments the value, like we had to do back in the Java times ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could create custom setters like this:

```
class Company(address: String, name: String, owner: String){
    var modified = LocalDateTime.now()

    var address: String = address
        set(value) {
            modified=LocalDateTime.now()
            field = value
        }
    var name: String = name
        set(value) {
            modified=LocalDateTime.now()
            field = value
        }

    var owner: String = owner
        set(value) {
            modified=LocalDateTime.now()
            field = value
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go more "kotlin" style, use an Observable property, otherwise Ivo's answer is fine, like what you'd do with Java.

```
class Company() {
    var modified = LocalDateTime.now()
        private set

    var address: String by Delegates.observable(address) { _, _, _ ->
        modified = LocalDateTime.now()
    }
   
    var name: String by Delegates.observable(name) { _, _, _ ->
        modified = LocalDateTime.now()
    }

    var owner: String by Delegates.observable(owner) { _, _, _ ->
        modified = LocalDateTime.now()
    }
}
```

If you truly want a "secondary constructor" to initialize at creation time, that's fine, just use different names, and/or private/getter/setters, etc.

E.g.:

```
class Company(initialAddress: String = "", 
              initialName: String = "", 
              initialOwner: String = "") {
    
    var modified = LocalDateTime.now()
        private set
    
    var address: String by Delegates.observable(initialAddress) { _, _, _ ->
        updateModified()
    } 
   
    var name: String by Delegates.observable(initialName) { _, _, _ ->
        updateModified()
    }

    var owner: String by Delegates.observable(initialOwner) { _, _, _ ->
        updateModified()
    }

    private fun updateModified() {
        modified = LocalDateTime.now()
    }
      
}
```

Comment: Why the additional `getModified()` getter instead of making the built-in getter of the `modified` property public?

Comment: II wouldn't want to expose a lot of mutable properties on a class, unless you're intentionally aware that anybody could do `company.modified = ...` thus mutating your class' internal state. It's just habit. That's how I would probably do it if I didn't know any more requirements. But it's out of habit, you could use any other syntax, it was just written in the Playground and there's no "auto-complete" there.

Comment: I updated it to use the built-in getter.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I didn't mean to expose the mutable property as a whole, just the read-only part of it, with `private set`. I think this is more idiomatic and just as safe in terms of what it exposes